# in C# Redis : could not connect to redis Instance at 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: c#, redis

In C# while using the Redis Server. I had initiated the redis server.

while connecting to redis server via c# code

I am using nuget package ServiceStack.Redis.

```
redisClient = new RedisClient("127.0.0.1", 6379);
```

Exception :

> base  {"could not connect to redis Instance at
>   127.0.0.1:6379:6379"} System.Exception {ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException}

but I am and able to connect to server via server_client.exe

Do we need to do something else to connect to redis? As I am Completely new to redis.

Comment: Have you checked why the exception lists the port number twice?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to redis-server at **127.0.0.1:6379** than you will need Redis a [redis-server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows) running locally.

You can test redis-server is running locally by running `redis-cli.exe` on the same server where you're trying to connect with [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).

Comment: Thanks mythz, its working now, i donot know the reson behind it but when i added a null check condition above it. its start working.                 if(redisClient==null)
redisClient = new RedisClient("127.0.0.1", 6379);